# 5 Volt power supply using lipo batteries in parallel( using Booster)

Tags: power-supply, batteries, raspberry-pi, dc-dc-converter

[image]

In the circuit above, i was able to read a current of 1.7 Amps using a multimeter at the o/p of the converter. But once i connect a raspberry pi at the output, the raspberry pi does not seem to run properly. What might be the problem? PS: the output voltage is 5.2V

Comment: Is the 5.2v with the Pi connected or disconnected?  You need to measure the voltage with the Pi connected.

Comment: @HandyHowie 5.2 V is with the Pi disconnected. With the Pi connected i am able to get around 5.08V at the output

Comment: How did you measure the current again? What exactly do you mean "does not seem to run properly"? What's wrong?

Comment: @Nazar Well, i shorted the O/p using multimeter actually, but only for about 3-4 seconds. The raspberry pi's green led blinks about twice and then flickers a third time, this pattern repeats. Or both the red and green led remains 'ON'.

Comment: Please, don't measure the current the way you did. Put your multimeter in series with the RaspPi. Then, look at the RaspPi datasheet to see if the measured voltage and current are reasonable (withing normal range according to the datasheet). If the power is alright, then look at the datasheet as see what the blinking signals indicate.

Comment: Measure the voltage at the input of the DC-DC converter with the Pi connected. Are you trying to run from the batteries or the charger input (Vcc)?

Comment: @Nazar, i tried connecting the multimeter in series to the rpi, It was drawing about 250 mA. But why is it drawing only that much when the circuit can provide much more than that. The rpi will run smoothly when it draws around 300-350 mA.

Comment: @Finbarr, I am trying to run from the batteries mainly, the Mosfet and all is used for load sharing when the charger is connected

Comment: The rpi will draw as much as it wants, subject to your supply being able to deliver it.

Comment: @Finbarr, what do you think might be the problem then?

Comment: "Measure the voltage at the input of the DC-DC converter with the Pi connected" - I asked that to help figure out what the problem might be.

Answer (score -1):

I used thicker and shorter wires from the batteries to the circuit. That helped.